# after mod-rewrite, all images file paths are not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add an url rewrite to a website and when I try to access the page it's loading with no images and css file.
Here is my code:

```
 < rewriter>
    < rewrite url="~/item/(.+)/(.+)" to="~/item.aspx?imageId=$1&amp;category=$2"/>
  < /rewriter>
 and 

 < location path="~/item.aspx">
    < system.web>
      < authorization>
        < allow users="*" />
      < /authorization>
    < /system.web>
  < /location>
```

but it seems it is not recognize the path.
Does anyone what is wrong ?

Thank you,
Alina

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allow access to the elements such as the cascading style sheets, images, other resources, wherever these are located - you can do this using a `<location>`, just as you've done for the page.

The tilde (`~`) in the path is unnecessary too, I think.

As an example:

```
<location path="path/to/styles/style.css">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="path/to/images">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```